# Salesforce SDOC - use Conditional SOQL query inside related list

Tags: soql

Requirement is:-

Let's say there is one campaign named is "Campaign 1", now under this campaign there are three campaign member. now based on the button click system needs to generate pdf where user can see those related contacts with their related campaign.  Here is the code snippet:-

```
<!--{{!
<lineitems><class>table257</class>
<listname>campaignmembers</listname>
<column>Contact.id</column>
<lineitemsSOQL>
<listname>campaignmember</listname>
<soql>
SELECT Campaign_Type__c  FROM CampaignMember where ContactId="{{!Contact.Id}}"</soql>
<column>Campaign_Type__c</column>
</lineitemsSOQL>
</lineitems>
}}-->
```

but it is not working. can we use dynamic soql in the `<lineitems>`? Otherwise how to show those records in SDOC?

Comment: By SDOC do you mean the third-party document generation package S-Docs?

Comment: Yap...can u help.me on this